# How to convert Google API DateTime timestamp between Cloud and local time

Tags: android, google-tasks-api

```
        //Push Insert a Task:
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  long timestampToDB = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    com.google.api.services.tasks.model.Task newTask = new com.google.api.services.tasks.model.Task();
    newTask.setTitle("New Task");
    DateTime timeStampLocale = new DateTime(calendar.getTime(), calendar.getTimeZone());
    newTask.setUpdated(timeStampLocale);

    //Pull the Task:
    com.google.api.services.tasks.model.Task theTask = Tasks.geTaskById(String taskId);
    DateTime timeStampCloud = theTask.getUpdated();

    //Compare Timestamp:
    //How to compare the two timestamp, in order to see which timestamp one is latest
```

I had "timeStampCloud" and "timestampToDB", but how to campare the two timestamp?
if the device timezone changed, what it will be going to happen. Please help!! :)

Comment: Convert local time to google timezone. And using compare method you compare both time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
 formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
 System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
 formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens")); System.out.println(formatter.format(instance2.getTime()))
```

Get timezone of google date..
According to that time convert your date to google timezone.. as shown in above examples.
Now you compare both dates..